# How to assign a specific kafka consumer to a specific partition

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have a "topic" with 2 partitions.

```
topic-0
topic-1
```

And I have 2 input message channels

```
input0
input1
```

with same destination "topic" and same group.

My understanding is that, since it is a same group each topic will be automatically assigned a partition.

Is possible to assign a specific partition to a specific message channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign specific partitions to Kafka consumer with consumer's `auto-rebalance` disabled along with the appropriate `instanceCount` and `instanceIndex` properties.

For instance, in your case,

`--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input0.consumer.instanceCount=2 --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.consumer.instanceCount=2 --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input0.consumer.instanceIndex=0 --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.consumer.instanceIndex=1 --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input0.group=mygroup --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.group=mygroup --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input0.consumer.autoRebalanceEnabled=false --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input1.consumer.autoRebalanceEnabled=false --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input0.destination=topic --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=topic`

The above configuration will assign the topic's partitions for each consumer (when binding the input channels) based on the modulo using the `partition` , `instanceCount` and `instanceIndex` values.

Comment: Thanks for help me. but how can i produce the message into specific partition. Anyone can help me.

Comment: You need to set the producer properties in this case. You can refer the doc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-snapshot/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_producer_properties